# Border radius and table issues in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, html, css

I might have worded the title wrong, ah well.

My (1st) problem i'm experiencing is this. Border radius isn't working in IE9 on my site. Every other site seems to be fine.

My CSS:

```
border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
```

My second problem is this,
In every browser but IE the div connects to the side of the border like so:
Chrome, FF, Safari - http://minus.com/me2JZyhlm

But in IE:
IE - http://minus.com/mbnYXszVfs

How would I go about fixing this?
--UPDATE-- Added Demo: http://thedailyvids.com/demo.php

```
 div.sidefeed {
        font-size: 11px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: black;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 140px;
        margin-right: -10px;
        font-family: calibri, arial;
    }
    div.sidefeed.active {
        font-size: 13px;
        color: black;
        padding: 5px;
        font-family: calibri, arial;
        background-color: #747474;
        border-left: 2px solid #5b5a5a;
    }
    div.sidefeed.active a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }
    div.sidefeed a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Why does IE have to be a tricky bitch! -_-

Comment: IE is the bane of all web developers, except those building corporate intranets running on IE6

Comment: So sick of this bullshit IE gives me. Seriously, it's ridiculous.

Comment: @Jake It's not fair to blame IE9 (which is a fine browser) if you create invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `border-radius` property works fine on IE 9 in “standards mode.” Either your page triggers Quirks Mode or it contains something that breaks things up. Regarding this and the other question, please post a complete testable demo document (not just screenshots) if you need more advice.

Comment: I'll make up a demo real quick.

Comment: @Jake Add `<!doctype html>` to the top of your markup. Then, most of your issues should be resolved. You see, it's not so tough to deal with new version of IE.

Comment: The demo does show any rounded border on Firefox either. It triggers Quirks mode. The HTML markup is invalid and the CSS code has about a hundred syntax errors reported by the W3C CSS Validator.

Comment: the demo doesn't have any border radius-es.